# I am using react-native-camera for video recording in my React Native App. I want to add timer in it

Tags: react-native, video, react-native-camera

This is my code for recording a video

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R32yV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [react-native-stopwatch-timer](https://github.com/michaeljstevens/react-native-stopwatch-timer) package, then you can use their `Stopwatch` component to start the timer, example code is already mentioned in the package. Hope this works for you!

Comment: I am getting this warning after I imported the package. "Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 18.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: StopWatch"

Comment: This warning is maybe related to the library, so you can simply go to that library path in your `node_modules`, find where the `StopWatch` component is implemented and see if the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle is used somewhere in that component then rename that with `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: I already implemented that scenario with the same library, you can see that here https://github.com/shoaiburrehman/AwesomeCamera/blob/master/src/Camera.js